# Flexbox order of tiles with variable widths

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a grid of tiles I need to display.

Article tiles can fit 4 in a row.

Videos can fit 2 in a row.

The problem I'm running into is this: a row with article, article, article, video. The video is bumped to the next line.

Or article, video, video. Again the second video gets bumped to the next line.

Setting the order property seems to be a pain because the order that articles / videos are shown is totally random. Is there a a good way to handle this problem with flexbox?

Here's the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/nx4ap9u4/ (in this case I'm trying to have 2 blue blocks and green block in the first row, 4 blue blocks in the second row without me having to set the order with CSS or JS)

```css
.blog-feeder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.article-preview.grid {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
}

.article-preview.grid.post_VIDEO {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-feeder">
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid post_VIDEO"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try to clean up my code for posting.  I should clarify, I'm fine with re-ordering the articles / videos somewhat so they fit nicely in a grid.  I would just like CSS to handle the re-ordering rather than doing it with jQuery, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of layout algorithm is beyond the capacity of flexbox. Items in a flex container cannot be re-ordered automatically to fill a row.

However, this feature is available in another CSS3 technology, **Grid Layout**.

The "dense" packing algorithm of the `grid-auto-flow` property enables grid items to be automatically re-ordered to fill empty space in a row.

*From the spec:*

> [**7.7. Automatic Placement: the `grid-auto-flow`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property)
>
> Grid items that aren’t explicitly placed are automatically placed into
>   an unoccupied space in the grid container by the auto-placement
>   algorithm.
>
> `grid-auto-flow` controls how the auto-placement algorithm works,
>   specifying exactly how auto-placed items get flowed into the grid.
>
> ***`dense`***
>
> If specified, the auto-placement algorithm uses a “dense” packing
>   algorithm, which attempts to fill in holes earlier in the grid if
>   smaller items come up later. This may cause items to appear
>   out-of-order, when doing so would fill in holes left by larger items.

```css
.blog-feeder {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.article-preview.grid {
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  background: blue;
}

.article-preview.grid.post_VIDEO {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-feeder">
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid post_VIDEO"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid post_VIDEO"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid post_VIDEO"></div>
  <div class="article-preview grid"></div>
</div>
```

[**revised demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nx4ap9u4/1/)

Here's how it works:

- The `.blog-feeder` element becomes a grid container with `display: grid`.
- The `grid-template-columns` property sets the grid to four columns, each having a width of `1fr`, which is an equal distribution of available space. (It's similar to `flex-grow: 1` in flexbox.)
- There are no *explicit* rows specified. But any rows created automatically by the grid (aka, *implicit* rows) will have a height of 100px. (Formerly 300px height on flex items in original code. Switched only for demo purposes.)
- The `grid-auto-flow` property sets the layout algorithm. `dense` will take items out of source order if necessary to fill gaps.
- The `grid-gap` property sets the space between items (the gutters). This property works only between items; it has no effect on the space between items and the container.

So far, all commands are set at the container level. This is different than flexbox, where many similar commands must be set on flex items.

- On the grid items themselves, the `span` value in the `grid-column-end` property is telling each item how many columns to cover.

---

**Browser Support for CSS Grid**

- Chrome - full support as of March 8, 2017 (version 57)
- Firefox - full support as of March 6, 2017 (version 52)
- Safari - full support as of March 26, 2017 (version 10.1)
- Edge - full support as of October 16, 2017 (version 16)
- IE11 - no support for current spec; supports obsolete version

Here's the complete picture: http://caniuse.com/#search=grid